# How to detect a service type in a grpc request packet from client?

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

I am new to  grpc and the services supported example gnmi, gnoi-file, gnoi-system etc. I want a single server to support multiple services and be able to spwan agent based on the service type. To detect the service type, I would like to access the metadata of the client request. Is it possible to detect service type before registering a service on the server. How can I do it?